# How to display time in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdate

I have an application in `Objective-C`. I have an `NSDate`, of `2014-01-01`, which I have displayed on the screen.

What I want is a way to increment the date after a time interval. For example, every 5 seconds, the date should increment by one day.

I want this to happen independently of other tasks, maybe on another thread. I will have other operations happening during this date updating.

EDIT: Solved!

Comment: What have you tried? I would start by incrementing your `NSDate` on the main thread to familiarize yourself with its methods. Then, focus on moving that operation to a background thread.

Comment: I know how to increment the date, I just don't know how to do it independently of other operations. I want it so that whatever the user is doing, the date keeps incrementing. I don't know where I should put that increment.

Comment: neither xcode nor xcode 5 are programming languages.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Incoming edit.

Comment: also xcode 5 is not a runtime environment. it is just an editor.

Comment: Point taked. I removed the reference to Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use NSTimer 
When it fires, change the date. 
But you need to read about NSDate. 
What you have is implicitly midnight. 
NSDate is an exact point in time and that means time is part of it. 
NSTimeZone is also part of it. 
NSCalendar as well. 
Together they give you a human readable value from an NSTimeInterval value which is what NSDate wraps in an object and is the number of seconds since the reference date positive or negative.

The problem is some dates have no midnight and some have two. 
So implicit midnight will screw up calendrical calculation. 
Set the time to noon. 
Then use one of the awesome new methods in 10.9 but only in the NSDate.h header and not in the docs still.

Comment: I understand what you've said about NSTimer and about the other aspects of NSDate. I've actually covered all of those aspects, I just didn't mention them.

What I didn't understand is how I can have a repeating NSTimer. If I put the timer in viewDidLoad or something, won't execution get stuck there forever?

Basically how do I do the NSTimer in the background?

Comment: Also, just to clarify, my issue is not with NSDate or NSTimer methods. My issue is where I should put the NSTimer.

Comment: The timer needs to be a property of an object that will live as long as you want the timer. You can invalidate the timer at any time you like. It could be in your app delegate unless it needs to be associated to something else.

Comment: Yes, thanks! I didn't know that the NSTimer continued on its own, but Alan posted the code so I now know that your solution is correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
    @implementation ViewController{

        NSDateFormatter *dateFormat;
        NSString *changedDate;
    }


    -(void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        [self getDate];
        [self update]; 
    }

-(void)getDate{

    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];
    NSLog(@"Today is: %@", dateString);
    changedDate = dateString;

}
-(void)update{

    NSDate *d = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: 0];
    NSTimer *t = [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate: d
                                          interval: 1
                                            target: self
                                          selector:@selector(addOneDay:)
                                          userInfo:nil
                                           repeats:YES];

    NSRunLoop *runner = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    [runner addTimer:t forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

}
-(void)addOneDay:(NSTimer*)timer
{

    NSDate *getDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:changedDate];
    int oneDayInterval = 24 * 60 * 60; //in seconds
    NSDate *newDate = [getDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:oneDayInterval];
    changedDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:newDate];
    NSLog(@"new Date: %@",changedDate);
}



@end
```

Comment: Thanks, but won't [self update] only run once, in viewDidLoad? So the timer will run only twice? What about after viewDidLoad, when I want other methods to be called from my app?

Comment: the update function is only called once (when the view did load) but the timer inside the update function calls the addOneDay function every second ... if that answers your question...? :)

Comment: Nevermind, thank you so much! This works perfectly! I tried it out.